# Independent Probability | Duplicate numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, birthday

$11$ numbers between $1$ and $40$ are select. What is the probability there are some duplicated integers in those $11$?

I think the answer to this question is very straightforward: $1-P(\text{they are all different})$

Is this correct? Suppose I have $3$ equal numbers, does that still count as one duplicate? or $2$?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel but it is not clear if triples are allowed.

Comment: Triples will also be removed from consideration by taking the complement.

Comment: Whether three equal numbers counts as one duplicate or two is irrelevant to your question, which is only about whether there is *some* duplicate. A question that asked about the number of duplicates would have to specify precisely how to count them.

Comment: @JoshSmith Don't worry about duplicates! All you need is to ensure that they are not all different from each other. The probability of them all being different, is easily calculable.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen is it just $1-\frac{40!}{(40-11)!40^{11}}$? But that is too high.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг is it just $1-\frac{40!}{(40-11)!40^{11}}$? But that is too high.

Comment: The number of ways of picking the numbers is $40^{11}$. To satisfy the condition of non-duplication, one must choose $11$ different numbers, and permute them, so that is $^{40}P_{11}$. So the answer is exactly what you have written, which evaluates to about $0.22$. That is, with fairly high probability, you will get duplicates. This is similar to the birthday paradox : there you have days of the year, and it takes just $23$ people to get more than half a chance of two people having the same birthday. In general, uniform picking gives a duplicate whp for $O(\sqrt n)$ samples.

Comment: @JoshSmith Why is that too high? I agree with астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг that what you have (78%) is the right answer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen it is kinda hard to believe that just a drawing of 11 numbers already gives a 78% probability of duplication. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the selections are independent and uniformly distributed, this is an example of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), but with $d=40$ rather than $365$

You are correct to calculate $1-P(\text{they are all different})$ and that in this case this gives $1-\frac{40!}{(40-11)!40^{11}} \approx 0.78$

Indeed the probability exceeds $0.5$ with $8$ selected from $40$, corresponding to the $23$ from $365$ in the classic birthday problem

A slightly different question would be the expected number of distinct days selected, which would be $40-\left(1-\left(\frac{39}{40}\right)^{11}\right)\approx 9.72$, substantially less than $11$, so you should not be surprised that the probability of having duplicated dates is high